# Changing Container Height

Tags: height, containers, wrapper, css

I am going through some minor issues here.  I am using a standard container height and css code for all pages.  For most pages there is enough content to fill it and for some the content may only take 10-20% of the page.  So is it a good idea for those pages to use a different min-height?  Below is the code:

```
#wrapper {
   background-color: #999999;
   margin:0 auto; 
   min-height: 600px;
   width:770px;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, 
   sans-serif;
   font-size:15px;
   color: #222222;
   margin-left:60px;
   margin-bottom:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to declare the lesser `min-height` in a separate class.

Then, you could do `<div id="wrapper" class="smallerContent">`.

```
#wrapper.smallerContent {
    min-height: 300px
}
```